# discord.py - How to make a response when a user doesn't have perms to ban a user

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to make it that when you try to ban a user, but you dont have perms, it sends a message instead of just an error. Anyone have a fix?

```
@bot.tree.command(name='ban', description='Ban a user. (w/ perms only)')
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def ban(ctx,member : discord.Member,* , reason: str):
    """Ban a user"""
    await ctx.response.send_message(member.name + " has been from banned the server for "+reason)
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
```

i tried except: and else: but it didnt really work. Im very new to python and im not sure how to do this.

Edit: Does anyone know how to make the bot send a message when it tries to ban a admin and improper perms for the bot? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a simple if statement which checks if the user has the permission to [ban members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Permissions.ban_members):

```py
if not ctx.user.guild_permissions.ban_members:
  return await ctx.response.send_message("You are not allowed to do this!")
```

Comment: it worked, thank you!

Comment: but do you know how to make it send a message when you try to ban an admin?

Comment: its similar like my example but this time you would check if the member is a admin.